# Share a link in whatsapp web with get data

Tags: html, get, whatsapp

I have a web application and in that, I am trying to share a link to WhatsApp web application and Mobile app.

The Mobile app link is working fine.

`<a target="_blank" href="whatsapp://send?text='http://uaereb.com/property-details/?property_id=41" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp whatsapp"></a>`

But for the web, the get value is not coming.

`<a target="_blank" href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=http://uaereb.com/property-details/?property_id=41"></a>`

The shareable link is coming as "http://uaereb.com/property-details/?property_id=" in the WhatsApp web.

Could anyone tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of = use **%3D** because whatsapp for web only reads urlencoded language or something like that there for ? you would use **%3F** and for spaces in your string you would use **%20**

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the message to be sent.
https://www.url-encode-decode.com/?_ga=2.169715105.1084578027.1543263981-326105195.1543263981

New Update: Nov 2018

```
<a href="https://wa.me/?text=<<HERE GOES THE URL ENCODED TEXT YOU WANT TO SHARE>>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

And that's it. No Javascript needed, nothing else needed. and if you want go a create a nice Whatsapp icon applying the styles.

If you want to know more about url encoding, [please follow this link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)